# Snakemake: Does not want to execute my rule?

Tags: python, workflow, pipeline, snakemake

I'm a beginner with coding and Snakemake and I'm really struggling to understand my problem. Running the snakefile below will produce no error. But it does not execute the Bowtie rule. After using --dryrun it will show:

> Building DAG of jobs... Nothing to be done.

My guess would be that I mixed something up with the wildcards and Snakemake thinks the file already exist so it does not execute the rule at all. The rule does work when I hard code it. I tried to change the wildcards but can't get it to run.

```
#Snakefile 
configfile: "../../config/config.yaml"

INPUTDIR = str(config["paths"]["input"])
OUTPUTDIR = str(config["paths"]["output"])
FILE_FORMAT = str(config["paths"]["file_format"])
DATABASEPATH = str(config["database"]["Bowtie_Database"])

(SAMPLES, NUMBERS) = glob_wildcards(INPUTDIR + "/{sample}_{number, [1,2]}." + FILE_FORMAT)
DATABASE, = glob_wildcards(DATABASEPATH + "/{bowtie_ref}")
#Outputfiles 
rule all:
    input:
        #FastQC raw
        expand(OUTPUTDIR + "/FastQC/raw/{sample}_{number}_fastqc.html", sample=SAMPLES,number=NUMBERS),
        expand(OUTPUTDIR + "/FastQC/raw/{sample}_{number}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLES,number=NUMBERS),
        #Bowtie output
        expand(OUTPUTDIR + "/Bowtie/{bowtie_ref}_{sample}.sam", bowtie_ref=DATABASE,sample=SAMPLES),
        #macs2 output
        #"/home/henri/MPI/Pipeline/Mus/results/Macs2/eg2.bed"
    

#######
# Q C #
#######

#Quality Control for raw data with FastQC 
rule qc_raw_fastqc:
    params:
        threads = config["threads"]
    conda: 
        "envs/fastqc.yml"
    input:
        INPUTDIR + "/{sample}_{number}." + FILE_FORMAT
    output:
        html = OUTPUTDIR + "/FastQC/raw/{sample}_{number}_fastqc.html",
        zip = OUTPUTDIR + "/FastQC/raw/{sample}_{number}_fastqc.zip"
    message:
        "Doing quality control for raw reads with FastQC"
    shell:
        "fastqc -o {config[paths][output]}/FastQC/raw {input}"


################
## B O W T I E #
################

#mapping on ref. genome with Bowtie2
#rule Bowtie:
    params:
        threads = config["threads"]
    conda:
        "envs/fastqc.yml"
    input:
        expand(INPUTDIR + "/Bowtie_Database/{{bowtie_ref}}{ending}", ending=[".1.bt2",".2.bt2",".3.bt2",".4.bt2",".rev.1.bt2",".rev.2.bt2"]),
        R1 = INPUTDIR + "{sample}.fastq",
        R2 = INPUTDIR + "{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        OUTPUTDIR + "/Bowtie/{bowtie_ref}_{sample}.sam"
    message:
        "Alignment with Bowtie2 this will take a while"
    shell:
        "bowtie2 -x {INPUTDIR}/{wildcards.bowtie_ref} -1 {input.R1} -2 {input.R2} -S {output}"
```

Any help or Ideas would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you paste the command that you try to run and what is the output.

Comment: One possible reason is that you've created the target files already.

Comment: Thanks I got it running I had a typo in the config file...

Answer (score 0):

@DmitryKuzminov is probably right - the output files exist and they are newer than the input.

You can force the re-execution of rule `Bowtie` (and everything that depends on its output) with:

```
snakemake --forcerun Bowtie ...
```